# Excel VBA summary paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried using the following answer: (specified for my use)

```
Sub MakeSummary()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long, M As Long
    N = Sheets.Count - 1
    M = 2
    For i = 1 To N
        Sheets(i).Range("A12:B17").Copy
        Sheets("AllInfo").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("AllInfo").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        M = M + 6
    Next i
End Sub
```

I can't seem te get this macro to paste next to each other, I can see the M is for pasting under each other but how do I get this macro to past next it I tried to do M=M+A since it is a column but it does not work.

Comment: in your case"M" is not a column, since you are using it with `.Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial` , so you are pasting it to Range("A2"), then Range("A8"), etc...

Comment: @ShaiRado but how do I get it is past next to each other ?

Comment: if you want to advance the columns, let's say for row 1, and advance the `M` like you wanted, then use `Sheets("AllInfo").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)` instead

Comment: @ShaiRado that it could be this easy, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ShaiRado

> if you want to advance the columns, let's say for row 1, and advance the M like you wanted, then use
>
> `Sheets("AllInfo").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)`
> instead – @Shai Rado

Comment: depending on the width of your to paste columns (in my case 2 wide) change M